# onkeypress , onkeyup are not working in textarea.

Tags: javascript, textarea

```
<textarea name="textarea" cols="20" rows="5" id="controller-about-information-about" onKeyDown="callname1(this.value);" onKeyPress="callname1(this.value);" onKeyUp="callname1(this.value);"></textarea>
<script>
    function callname1(str) {
        alert(str);
        alert("this is textarea");

    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is the question? This code seems to work fine.

Comment: It surely works for me! What is the functionality that you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in an XHTML document, all attribute names have to be in lowercase (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/diffs.html#h-4.2) if you want the document to be valid. I am not sure if it makes your code "not working".